# Function takes priority over Timer?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am new to vb.net and was wondering why my function (Run_Process) takes priority over the timer?

The timer (which starts the progress bar) runs after the function call even though the timer is set before the function.

```
                Timer2.Start()
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Backing up the registry, Please wait as this may take some time...")
                ListBox1.ForeColor = Color.SlateBlue
                MsgBox(Run_Process("CMD.exe", "/C regedit.exe /e C:\MMG\Regbackup.Reg"))
                Timer2.Stop()
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
```

The function itself runs a cmd command.

The timer code is

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick    
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1) 
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 And ListBox1.Items.Count() < 1 Then 
        Label1.Text = "Process complete with no obvious threats" 
        Button4.Enabled = False 
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen 
        Button1.Enabled = False 
    End If 
    Label3.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & (" %") 
End Sub
```

Comment: And the interval of the Timer is?

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: The timer code is Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 And ListBox1.Items.Count() < 1 Then
            Label1.Text = "Process complete with no obvious threats"
            Button4.Enabled = False
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
            Button1.Enabled = False
        End If
        Label3.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & (" %")
    End Sub

Comment: Still not sure about your problem. Is it that you are not seeing the progress bar changes?

Comment: The bar starts after the function although I have set the bar to start first as the above code

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing concepts.

You start the timer, and I suppose it's waiting Interval period prior to launch Tick Event. Meanwhile, your launching a CMD. Are you waiting for exit, or it's running in async mode?
Then, you stop the timer.... your progress bar could be on 10% or 4% ....

I mean: your cmd process and your timer, are not connected anyway.

- How are launching CMD process?
- Your timer it's growing from "1%" to "100%", in what interval? +1 every 1000 milisecs? 3000 milisecs? ... Your progress bar can be finished, and your CMD be still running.

If I were you, I would use a Thread or better a Task to perform this. But, you can consider to forget your Timer, and use a ProgressBar1.Style=Marquee", instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I think I will look more into how the timer works as I am a beginner and also look at maybe using the "Marquee"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use Run_Process from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152531/how-to-run-cmd-exe-command-with-visual-basic-code), the Call probably blocks until the process ends so your UI thread is not able to act on the timer event. I think you need to brush up on [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Threadpool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and likes.

In general you should use something like this pseudocode:

```
Start a BackgroundWorker that
    Starts the Process
    Reads the Output
    Reports Progress (and ListBox Elements) via ReportProgress
Meanwhile your UI Thread
    Handles the BackgroundWorkers ProgressChanged Event
    Updates ListBox and ProgressBar
    Exits when BackgroundWorker is done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I think I will look more into how the timer works as I am a beginner and also look at maybe using the "Marquee"

Comment: In Short, the timer simply sends (or rather "raises") an event to your foreground or UI thread. If it is busy in a loop or waits for an input your Tick() will not run, nor will your Window react to user actions. Using a BackgroundWorker will often improve the usability of your apps because your UI can continue to react the user.

Comment: Great. Is there any specific reference or examples I can look at with regards to "background worker" just to see how it would work?

Comment: The Link above has an VB Example inside: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2