# vbScript that Checks NetworkAdapter Config and updates URL if it detects change

Tags: vbscript

Ok... everyone here seems to be way more educated about this stuff than I. But I've been at this for 2 days straight and I've gone at it from all kinds directions.

Goal:

Have a script check the IP address of local pc. At some time (thinking 5 minutes) recheck the IP address again. Compare the two and if there is a change execute a command silently.

I realize that I can not just get the IP address as I'll get the entire state using winmgmts and I'm ok with that. Really it's just to keep an eye on whether or not the state changes in general. The line of code is to access a URL which will update my FreeDNS incase the IP changes. For whatever reason, none of the programs offered have been working. One even crashes .Net Framework.

Knowing that I'm an utter noob (and thank you for reading this far!) here's what my crazy broken and utterly bizarre code looks like. Any assistance would be divine and I apologize

```
Dim firstSet, secondSet

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set FirstIP = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM " &    "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
Set firstSet = FirstIP

WScript.Sleep 3

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set SecondIP = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM " & "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
Set secondSet = SecondIP

results = StrComp(firstSet, secondSet, 1)

If Not results = True Then
    updateURL = "MyURL"
    Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    req.Open "GET", updateURL, False
    req.Send
End If
```

Comment: I suppose you want to check the IP address of one of the network interfaces? Localhost is generally considered 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes, check ip address of one network interface, but have not been able to confirm that checking one interface is possible so willing to take whatever it is that would work.

Comment: I don't use windows, but I suppose a simple way to get to the IP addresses is by capturing the output of the `ipconfig`. I guess that should be possible from VB.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but I lack the know-how on just how to do that. I took 1 class in college on vb-scripting and that  was in 2007!!

Comment: Well, I never programmed in VB at all, but google told me to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152531/how-to-run-cmd-exe-command-with-visual-basic-code If you also check the link there to StandardOutput, then you'll find how to capture the command's output. From there on, you just have to look in the string.

Comment: Talk about flawed logic. Two days and I just realized I'm an utter idiot. Sorry... Capturing ipconfig won't work either - pc is behind a firewall therefore the ip address will always be the same (it's static) private ip. I need to capture the public ip (non-static) address and I have no idea even how to begin on that notion. Wish I could figure out why none of the apps from FreeDNS work.... But there you have it folks.. Thanks for trying to assist. It's going to take someone with a heck of a lot more knowledge/skill than I to figure this out. Two days......TWO DAYS! Lol

Comment: Shouldn't be that difficult either. There are plenty of sites that tell you which IP you used to connect to them. https://www.whatismyip.com/ is one of them. So if you use the PC to connect to that site...