# How to write inside the cmd using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to show "Hello world" text inside the CMD editor, but when I use this code I get the result like this

[image]

I want the text to appear only .......

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Dim CMDprocess As New Process
    CMDprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
    CMDprocess.Start()
    Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = CMDprocess.StandardInput
    sw.WriteLine("Hello World")
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what your image looks like, because it's covered in adverts and spam.  I suggest you move it to imgur for stack overflow or similar.

Comment: When I run your code I get a blank console window.

Comment: Pretty clear. You are passing "Hello World" to a new process, and it sees "Hello" and doesn't know what that is. Try passing a quoted string that uses the "echo" command. This is also likely a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162196/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a Command Prompt command with Visual Basic code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152531/how-to-run-a-command-prompt-command-with-visual-basic-code)

Comment: Isnt it more about knowing how the command prompt works?  As the error explains "Hello" is not a valid command, app or batch file.  How would you print "Hello World" from the command prompt?  Not really a programming question.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems your code works well. Your "Hello World" is parsed by CMD.
If you want to write Text in CMD you can use "echo", so try `sw.WriteLine("echo Hello World")`

If you also don't want the command line appear there, try `sw.WriteLine("echo off")` at first.

I also recommend to take a look at

In addition:
As mentioned in the comments of your question, this problem is less related to VB than it is to windows command line. If you tag it like that you might get some more answers.