# How to run a command in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Im trying to run a command in visual studio. I want to run the command when I hit compile. Where do I put this command at?

```
fxc.exe /T fx_5_0 /Fo Basic.fxo Basic.fx
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out [How to run a Command Prompt command with Visual Basic code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152531/how-to-run-a-command-prompt-command-with-visual-basic-code)

i think the answer is :

```
Dim OpenCMD 
OpenCMD = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
OpenCMD.run(".../your directory/fxc.exe /T fx_5_0 /Fo Basic.fxo Basic.fx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

1. Go to your project properties by right click on project and from context menu click Properties
   [image]
2. Now on Project properties click on Build Events tab and here you can writes pre/post build event command line[image]